# VueJS: Render dynamic template for component

Tags: vue.js

I have a component on my parent page like so:

**Detail.vue**

Template:

```
<feature-list :description="description"></feature-list>
```

Script:

```
axios.get(`my/end/point`)
.then(res => {
  this.description = res.data.product.description
 })
 .catch(function (error) {
   console.log('error', error)
 })
```

Features.vue

Template:

```
<component :is="subcomponent" :height="overallHeight" :width="overallWidth" :length="overallLength"></component>
```

Script:

```
components: {
  subcomponent: {
    props: ['overallHeight', 'overallWidth', 'overallLength'],
    /* template: this.description */
  }
}
```

Expected return value from `this.description`:

```
  <el-row :gutter="30">
      <el-col :sm="24">
        <ul class="dimensions d-flex">
          <li class="dimension">
            <img src="/length.jpg" alt="">
            <h4 class="title">Length</h4>
            <p class="base-copy">{{length}}</p>
          </li>
          <li class="dimension">
            <img src="/height.jpg" alt="">
            <h4 class="title">Height</h4>
            <p class="base-copy">{{height}}</p>
          </li>
          <li class="dimension">
            <img src="/width.jpg" alt="">
            <h4 class="title">Width</h4>
            <p class="base-copy">{{width}}</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </el-col>
    </el-row>
```

How can I send the template to the component? and render the values (lenth, width and height)

Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/334318/), only difference being, the template comes from an ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

After some digging, I've found a way to solve this, the idea is to pass the `template` and the `props` as an object to the `is` prop.

The code will look like this,

```
<component 
 :is="description && { template: `<div>${description}</div>`, props: ['height', 'width', 'length'] }" 
 :height="overallheight" 
 :width="overallwidth" 
 :length="overalllength">
</component>
```